# Create new list in for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new list by changing the other in for loop, using append method. But I a have a trouble with it.

My simple code:

```
l1=[]
l2=[0,0]
for i in range(4):
    l2[0]+=1
    l1.append(l2)
    print l2
print l1
```

Return:

```
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
[[4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0]]
```

But I expected that list l1 would be like this: [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0]]
Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a copy of the list and not a reference to it.

```
l1.append(l2[:])
```

Test Run:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = [0, 0]
>>> for i in range(4):
        l2[0] += 1
        l1.append(l2[:])
        print l2


[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
>>> l1
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a reference to the list. And since, at the end of the loop, the value of `l2` is `[4,0]`, each list inside `l1` is `[4,0]`

You can just append a copy of the list with the help of the `list()` built-in method or, using the slicing notation as shown below

```
l1=[]
l2=[0,0]
for i in range(4):
    l2[0]+=1
    l1.append(list(l2)) # or l1.append(l2[:])
    print l2
print l1
```

If you are not able understand the idea, you can use the [viz mode of codeskulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/viz/index.html) and run the code line by line, understand it properly.